# ECDSA ciphering with OpenSSL results in memory problem

Tags: c, memory, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt a message using the ECDSA algorithm with OpenSSL (1.1.1), but I must be doing something wrong with my pointers, because everytime I run the code, it gives me a different result.

Here's what I do:

- create a key using custom curve parameters (with `BN_hex2bn`);
- sign a simple message using `ECDSA_do_sign`;
- split the message into the R and S points (`ECDSA_SIG_get0_r` and `ECDSA_SIG_get0_s`);
- display the resulting R point.

And the display value is always different, while I expect it to be the same (because same message and same key). I think some memory is deallocated somewhere, giving me a pointer to invalid data, but I'm not sure about it; I have checked:

- the keys are ok, and they are valid according to `EC_KEY_check_key`;
- the two variables `s` and `r` are already wrong, hence it doesn't come from `BN_bn2bin`.

Here is my code if you want to give a try:

```c
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>

int main(void) {
    ECDSA_SIG *sig;
    EC_KEY *eckey;

    BIGNUM *priv_key = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *x_key = BN_new();
    BIGNUM *y_key = BN_new();

    const char digest[] = "Hello, world!";

    eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);

    // Set predefined keys
    BN_hex2bn(&priv_key, "8e9b109e719098bf980487df1f5d77e9cb29606ebed2263b5f57c213df84f4b2");
    BN_hex2bn(&x_key, "7fcdce2770f6c45d4183cbee6fdb4b7b580733357be9ef13bacf6e3c7bd15445");
    BN_hex2bn(&y_key, "c7f144cd1bbd9b7e872cdfedb9eeb9f4b3695d6ea90b24ad8a4623288588e5ad");

    EC_KEY_set_private_key(eckey, priv_key);
    EC_KEY_set_public_key_affine_coordinates(eckey, x_key, y_key);

    sig = ECDSA_do_sign(digest, 32, eckey);

    // Get the resulting point
    const BIGNUM *r = ECDSA_SIG_get0_r(sig);
    const BIGNUM *s = ECDSA_SIG_get0_s(sig);

    unsigned char rc[256];
    unsigned char sc[256];

    BN_bn2bin(r, rc);
    BN_bn2bin(s, sc);

    // Print the result: some memory problem...
    for(int i = 0; rc[i] != 0; i++) {
        printf("%d ", rc[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Do no forget to link the libraries when you compile it: `gcc -g -o main main.c -lssl -lcrypto`.

Comment: Are you sure it's wrong? I think ECDSA is a randomized algorithm.

Comment: ECDSA is usually non-deterministic, so your assumption that the same digest with the same key should yield the same signature is not correct. A fresh, cryptographically-strong random integer needs to be generated for each signature, otherwise it's possible to solve for the private key.

Comment: That's for sure something I didn't know, thanks for your help.